# Removing characters, c#

Tags: c#, string, sharepoint

All,

I have names that I retrieve from Sharepoint.  These names our outputted in this format:

```
123;#David Putty
67;#Brian Star
```

The number are the ID's and I am unaware of how to remove the first few characters upto and including the # sign.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Show yur code - it helps us not guess and focus on your circumstances.

Comment: Look at `IndexOf` + `Substring`.. or `Split()` if you like. I think Split might be messy for your case.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way to do this is

```
var spflv = new SPFieldLookupValue(yourString);
int intPart = spflv.LookupId;
string stringPart = spflv.LookupValue;
```

Don't process the string yourself; use the correct Sharepoint classes to do it.

If you have the corresponding `SPWeb` to hand, you can even do

```
var spfuv = new SPFieldUserValue(yourWeb, yourString);
int intPart = spfuv.LookupId;
string stringPart = spfuv.LookupValue;
SPUser user = spfuv.User;
```

but this isn't necessary to just get the name part.

Answer (score 1):

```
string name = input.Split('#')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a Sharepoint solution, you can use a SPFieldUserValue class, something like:

```
new SPFieldUserValue(web, "123;#David Putty").User.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this trivial task.

Depending on your needs, I would think the simplest is:

```
string[] fields = s.Split(';');
```

Where `s` contains the data above. This will separate out the three fields.

Beyond that, see `String.Substring()` for ways to extract any portion of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string with `;` and return the second item:

```
string[] array = yourString.Split(';'); //yourString = 123;#David Putty
string whatYouWant = array[1];          //#David Putty
```

Answer (score 0):

For a single line, you can use Substring and IndexOf:

```
string line = "123;#David Putty";
line = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("#") + 1)
```